# Other than cash (always welcome), what donations might be of the greatest use for rescue organizations?

Tags: shelter

Not everyone can afford to give money to rescue organizations, but many might have supplies and equipment from prior pets that could be of use. Are there items that are often in short supply and might be very useful and valuable to rescue organizations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My local animal shelter maintains a [list of wanted items](http://www.thinkingoutsidethecage.org/site/c.elKWIeOUIhJ6H/b.8601603/k.9024/Shelter_Resident_Wish_List.htm) on its web site.  (Perhaps yours does too!)  Some themes from that list:

- *new* toys, collars, and litter pans
- durable equipment (not required to be new): leashes, beds, heating pads, nail clippers, pens, etc
- towels, blankets, and small rugs
- food (check with your shelter for any specific requests about flavor, brand, or form)
- pet-safe cleaning supplies
- newspapers
- electronics: cameras, printers, scanners, etc

Given a choice between donating money and using that money to buy something else to donate, I always donate the money -- I assume that they can get better bulk discounts on things like food than I can so the money will go farther.  But if I *already had* something that I couldn't use, I would check whether the shelter would take it.

Comment: That's a great idea. I know when our cat passed away we had a cupboard full of cat food we didn't know what to do with.

Comment: You might want to add cleaning supplies, especially bleach, and petsafe all purpose cleaner, and laundry soap.  Most rescues have a day or 2 of towels and blankets and basically turn them over and have to clean them every few days.

Comment: My shelter also uses newspapers, and loves old towels, sheets, blankets, etc. We go through a lot of hand sanitizer too.

Comment: My shelter often takes newspaper too, but currently they say they're inundated so they took it off the list and I didn't think to mention it.